# Expected reproduction rate of a dandelion and/or fern

Tags: botany, reproduction, population-biology

I am working a basic mathematical/computer simulation of an ecosystem, and I need to know the birth rate of each organism in my simulation. However, I could not find any data for how often a small, asexually-reproducing plant, like a fern or dandelion, reproduces. Does anybody know either a) the time to reach sexual maturity and the expected offspring of one dandelion or fern OR b) when starting with one plant, the expected living dandelion or fern plants after a year?

In other words, if I plant one dandelion or fern in a closed system (providing it with requisite water, food, sunlight, etc), how many can I expect to find at the end of the year?

These values don't have to be exact, I can adjust them later, but I need something to use as a baseline.

Answer (score 2):

Dandelions may have "from 54 to 172 seeds per head and a single plant can produce more than 2000 seeds" (https://fyi.uwex.edu/weedsci/2002/11/12/dandelion/), but the number of inflorescences depends, for example, on the age of the plant. It should also be remembered that some individuals repeat the blooming in autumn, although it is not so abundant (usually only one inflorescence). That, what is called a dandelion (Taraxacum officinale) is a collective species, which actually consists of several hundred microspecies, which may differ in the amount of seeds produced. Thus, the given data is only quoted.